# Proof Question: Let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$: If any open cover for $K$ has a finite subcover, then $K$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology

I have a question about the proof given by Stephen Abbott on theorem 3.3.8, specifically with this implication:

Let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$: If any open cover for $K$ has a finite subcover, then $K$ is closed.

He proceeded by proving it by contradiction, that is, if $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $K$, with $y=\text{lim}(y_n)$, then we assume $y\notin K$ (negating the conclusion that $K$ is closed). If $y\notin K$, then for any $x\in K$, they have a non-zero distance with $y$. Construct the open sets for each $x\in K$, by taking $O_x=V_{\epsilon}(x)$, where $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ is an $\epsilon$-nhood of $x$, and where $\epsilon = \frac{|x-y|}{2}$. Thus $\{O_x:x\in K \}$ is an open cover for $K$. By hypothesis, there should be a finite subcover from this open cover: $\{O_{x_1},O_{x_2},...,O_{x_n}\}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, set $$\epsilon_{0}=\min\left\{\frac{|x_i-y|}{2}:1\leq i \leq n \right\}.$$
Because $(y_n)\rightarrow y$, we can find a $n\geq N$, such that $|y_N-y|<\epsilon_0.$ But such a $y_N$ must be excluded from each $O_{x_i}$, meaning $$y_N \notin \bigcup_{i=1}^n O_{x_i}.$$ which is a contradiction since by hypothesis it should be $y_N \in K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n O_{x_i}$.

I am not sure:

1. Why it is necessary to use $\epsilon = \frac{|x-y|}{2}$, and
2. Why should $y_N$ be excluded from each $O_{x_i}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You choose this $\varepsilon$ to get a ball that includes $x$ but excludes $y$. This way the union of all these balls covers $K$ but does not include $y$.
2. You have $\vert y_N-y\vert<\varepsilon_0$. So $y_N$ is not contained in any of the finitely many balls that were chosen before: Otherwise $\vert y - x \vert \leq \vert y - y_N \vert + \vert y_N-x\vert < \varepsilon_0 +\frac 1 2 \vert y-x \vert$, which would be a contradiction since $\varepsilon_0 \leq \frac 1 2 \vert y - x \vert$.
   Since the $O_{x_i}$ are a cover of $K$ we conclude $y_N \notin K$.

Comment: Ok, the statement that $y_N$ is not contained in any of the finitely many balls (centered at $x_i$) formally say $|x_i-y_N| \geq \frac{1}{2}|x_i-y|$ right?

Comment: Yes. This is the definition of a ball/neighbourhood.